# How to call an event handler function from App.js in two other components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I created a reset function in App.js and want to call it by an onclick in two other components. the problem is that it works in one component but doesn't in the other.

Here are the codes snippets

**App.js**

```
    import React from 'react';
    import Result from './components/Result';
    import GeneralResult from './components/GeneralResult';

    class App extends Component {
     constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {

        result: '',
         counter: 0,
    }
    }

    // Reset function 
    handleReset=()=>{

        this.setState({
          result: '',
         counter: 0,
    )}

    renderResult() {
        return (
          <div>
     <Result reset={()=>this.handleReset()} />
    <GeneralResult back={()=>this.handleReset()} />

       </div>

        );
      }
```

**Result.js**

> first component making use of reset()

```
function Result(props) {
    return (
 <div>     
     <span>
         <button onClick={props.reset}>Replay</button>
     </span>                         
 </div>

  );
}

export default Result;
```

**GeneralResult.js**

> second component making use of the reset

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';

    export default class GeneralResult extends Component {


      render() {

          return (

            <React.Fragment>

            <h2>Congratulations you won!</h2>
            <span>
              <button onClick={props.back}> Back to Question</button>
              </span>

            </React.Fragment>
          );
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the handler as props, and render the component from the parent class.

```
class Child extends Component {
 render(){
     return(
         <button onClick = {this.props.onClick}></button>
     )
}
 }

 export default Child;
```

---

```
import Child from 'path/to/child';

class Parent extends Component {
  onClick = (e) => {
    //do something
}
render () {
    return(
        <Child onClick = {onCLick}/>
    )
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that `GeneralResult` is class based component. so when you need to access props passed to it. you have to use `this.props`.

```
export default class GeneralResult extends Component {
  render() {
      return (
        <React.Fragment>
          <h2>Congratulations you won!</h2>
          <span>
          // you need to change "props.back"
          // to "this.props.back"
          <button onClick={this.props.back}> Back to Question</button>
          </span>
         </React.Fragment>
      );
    }
  }
```

Comment: add console.log in `handleReset=()=>{
      console.log('handleReset Called');
        this.setState({
          result: '',
         counter: 0,
        })
    }` and see if it is called or not

Comment: and change `renderResult` to `render`